# File transfer in FTP

Tags: multithreading, ftp, c#-2.0

I want to transfer files using ftp in a simple and effective manner. For example, if we want to send a file means we just put the entire file with commands, but if it is a huge file and the network strength is low means automatically the transferspeed will be reduced.
What will be the effective method to transfer a huge file even the network strength is low?

Below is the piece of code where i get some error,please have a look at it.i employed threading here:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ArrayList AscendingList = new ArrayList();
    ListViewItem Litem = null;
    Thread MyThread = null;
    ThreadStart Starter = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_split_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem litem in listView1.Items)
        {
            Starter = delegate { SplitFile(litem.Text,litem.SubItems[1].Text,int.Parse(litem.SubItems[2].Text)); };
            MyThread = new Thread(Starter);
            MyThread.IsBackground = true;
            MyThread.Start();
        }
    }
    public void SplitFile(string inputFile, string outputPrefix, int chunkSize)
    {
        int pointr = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            int index = 0;
            pointr = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (pointr != 0)
            {
                using (FileStream fso = new FileStream(outputPrefix + "\\" + index + ".log", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    AscendingList.Add(fso.Name);
                    fso.Write(buffer, 0, pointr);
                    pointr = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Litem = new ListViewItem();
        Litem.Text = "E:\\butterfly.mpg";
        Litem.SubItems.Add("H:\\karthik");
        Litem.SubItems.Add("102400");
        listView1.Items.Add(Litem);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Litem = new ListViewItem();
        Litem.Text = "E:\\karthik.mpeg";
        Litem.SubItems.Add("H:\\karthik\\karthik");
        Litem.SubItems.Add("102400");
        listView1.Items.Add(Litem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I RESOLVED THE THREAD ISSUE,I PUT THE SPLITTING FUNCTIONALITY INTO A SEPARATE CLASS .I CREATE NEW INSTANCE FOR EVRY INPUT AND ASSIGN IT TO A THREAD.IT WORKS FINE NOW.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to accelerate your transfers.

> what will be the effective method to
>   transfer a huge file even the network
>   strngth is low

- [Split your file](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sayginteh/FileMergerandSplitterinCS12052005011745AM/FileMergerandSplitterinCS.aspx)
- [Thread your application so that you
  can send multiple requests at
  once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- [Send      each file via ftp to
  another       computer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FtpClient.aspx)
- [Recombine the file at     the other
  end](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sayginteh/FileMergerandSplitterinCS12052005011745AM/FileMergerandSplitterinCS.aspx)

This is assuming you wish to write the application yourself, using FTP.

Comment: hi i already used this method i have some difficulty while threading my application

Comment: Actually i am encrypting,compressing and splitting a file ,i put 
all these functionalities in a thread,while running the application
with multiples files it doesnt work it gives an exception "xx.dat" is in use.if it is a single file means it works fine.thats where
i got stuck up for the last one month

Comment: if my filesize is 350mb and that one is also a video file then what will happpen in that case? if i try splitting a video file of 350mb
without using thread means the ui will get hanged